# bootstrap grid layout questions

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZELOE.jpg

is there anyway to achieve the responsive grid layout above using bootstrap?

i not sure whether this is the correct way to do it?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://s27.postimg.org/twfuw219f/256x256.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3"><img src="http://s8.postimg.org/w0dxtotv9/256x120.jpg"></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3"><img src="http://s8.postimg.org/w0dxtotv9/256x120.jpg"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w3nta1/DTcHh/8581/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems that it's the right way to proceed: I modified your JSFiddle to give you an example ([there](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8584/))

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-eq-height">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://colouringbook.org/SVG/2011/COLOURINGBOOK.ORG/CBOOK/fotocamera_foto_camera_icon_coloring_book_colouring-2555px.png">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"><img
                        src="http://colouringbook.org/SVG/2011/COLOURINGBOOK.ORG/CBOOK/fotocamera_foto_camera_icon_coloring_book_colouring-2555px.png">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12"><img
                        src="http://colouringbook.org/SVG/2011/COLOURINGBOOK.ORG/CBOOK/fotocamera_foto_camera_icon_coloring_book_colouring-2555px.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You maybe need to manage the height of each column but the example [there](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/) explains that very well

(I'm not bootstrap expert, I prefer Foundation)

Comment: thanks for your help~ now i've clear idea how it works.. thanks :)